# Puppet Hiera lookup in manifest not working

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am learning Puppet and just read about Hiera.

Before coming to the issue, i'm providing some config settings below:

```
$ cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
[master]
codedir = /etc/puppetlabs/code

[agent]
server = puppet.example.com

[master]
certname = puppet.example.com

[master]
vardir = /var/opt/puppetlabs/puppetserver
ssldir = $vardir/ssl

[main]
environmentpath = /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments
basemodulepath = /etc/puppetlabs/code/modules


$ cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - common

:yaml:
# datadir is empty here, so hiera uses its defaults:
# - /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{environment}/hieradata on *nix
# - %CommonAppData%\PuppetLabs\code\environments\%{environment}\hieradata on Windows
# When specifying a datadir, make sure the directory exists.
  :datadir:
```

UPDATE: After going through @um-FelixFrank answer, i changed my default Hiera config file location. The config file has the following content:

```
$ cat /etc/puppetlabs/code/hiera.yaml
---
:backends:
 - yaml
:hierarchy:
 - "hostname/%{facts.hostname}"
 - "os/%{facts.osfamily}"
 - common
:yaml:
 :datadir: /etc/puppetlabs/code/hieradata
```

I created hieradata dir under `/etc/puppetlabs/code`

```
$ ll /etc/puppetlabs/code/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root  32 Dec 20 11:17 environments
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  39 Dec 21 12:22 hieradata
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 153 Dec 20 16:51 hiera.yaml
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   6 Dec 21 11:02 modules

$ cat /etc/puppetlabs/code/hieradata/common.yaml
---
puppet::status: 'running'
puppet::enabled: true
```

I tried overwriting the above values in my hostname yaml file as stated under:

```
$ cat /etc/puppetlabs/code/hieradata/hostname/delvmplgc1.yaml
---
puppet::status: 'stopped'
puppet::enabled: false

$ facter hostname
delvmplgc1
```

I created a sample manifest on Puppet server to see whether i am able to perform Hiera lookup in manifest.

```
$ cat /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/qa/manifests/hierasample.pp
notify { 'welcome':
        message => "Hello!",
}

$status = lookup({ name => 'puppet::status', default_value => 'running' })
$enabled = lookup({ name => 'puppet::enabled', default_value => true })

service { 'puppet':
        ensure => $status,
        enable => $enabled,
}
```

Now the problem is that when i try executing the manifest, i see no messages related to Hiera.

```
$ puppet apply /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/qa/manifests/hierasample.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for delvmplgc1.sapient.com in environment production in 0.99 seconds
Notice: Hello!
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[welcome]/message: defined 'message' as 'Hello!'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.10 seconds
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the contents of `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml` to the question?

Comment: Updated the post with the content of `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment in the standard `hiera.yaml` states, the `datadir` is located in

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{environment}/hieradata
```

So instead of creating `hieradata` in `/etc/puppetlabs/code` directly, move it down two levels into `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/qa` and other environments.

Comment: I tried changing the default hiera config file location instead using `hiera_config = $codedir/hiera.yaml` and it picked up the change. Thanks for pointing out the mistake! :)

Comment: There is still one query though: The overwritten values in the file delvmplgc1.yaml shown in my post changes both 'status' and 'enabled' to 'stopped' and false respectively. However, the puppet output only mentions: `Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Service[puppet]/ensure: ensure changed 'running' to 'stopped'`. It should have also mentioned `Notice: /Stage/Main/Service[puppet]/enable: enable changed 'true' to 'false'`. Any idea why it skipped that?

Comment: I have pasted the content of my custom hiera.yaml file in my post.

Comment: @Technext The output from your comment here is inconsistent with the output in your question. Also, Felix Frank told you to change your `hieradata` location, not your `hiera.yaml` location. You probably shouldn't have moved that.

Comment: @Technext do keep in mind that by making your Hiera data environment agnostic, you will not be able to stage changes in non-prod environments etc., so this is usually a bad move. As for perceived misbehavior, I advise to perform some lower level debugging, such as printing your variable values using `notify` and so forth. Finally, if this keeps acting up, please refrain from editing the question multiple times, and consider posing a new, more pointed question.

Comment: @MattSchuchard: The output in the comment is the one i got after changing the hiera config file location. BTW, i know Felix didn't ask me to change the config location. :) I wanted to try his suggestion and also wanted to see whether i can change the config location. It was purely done for testing purpose.

Comment: @um-FelixFrank: I completely agree that changing Hiera config location will not help me with using multiple environments. It's indeed bad but was done only as a test. I have moved the dir `hieradata` to the expected location. Actually, all this happened because i was reading 'Learning Puppet 4' which suggested (Chapter 11: Separating Data from Code) creating the `hieradata` dir inside `/etc/puppetlabs/code/`. Anyways, regarding the output issue, i will test using variables and if it happens again, i will post a fresh question. Thanks for your help.